# Repeater on QT Calendar displays incorrectly when month changed

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, repeat

I am working with the `QtQuick controls calendar`,

Within this calendar each date is highlighted if the corresponding date is within my database (stored as JSON) - Until now if there is multiple dates within the database, they are displayed only using a single marker (which has worked fine) (noted in the code eg). I am now looking to add a repeater to show multiple highlights, if the date exists more than once in my database.

The repeater is working (code below), but only on the month the calendar is opened in -when you change the visible month in the calendar the repeater either shows the markers on dates from the initial month the calendar was opened in, or not at all?

the code below is an example of my calendar, and below that some of the JSON (I have placed at the bottom for a working example)

```
    Flow {
        id: row
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 10
        layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
        Calendar {
            id: calendar
            width: (parent.width > parent.height ? parent.width * 0.6 - parent.spacing : parent.width)
            height: (parent.height > parent.width ? parent.height * 0.6 - parent.spacing : parent.height)
            selectedDate: new Date()
            focus: true
            style: CalendarStyle {
                id: calendarStyle
                navigationBar: Rectangle {
                    height: Math.round(TextSingleton.implicitHeight * 2.73)
                    color: "#f9f9f9"
                    Rectangle {
                        color: Qt.rgba(1,1,1,0.6)
                        height: 1
                        width: parent.width
                    }
                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                        height: 1
                        width: parent.width
                    }
                    HoverButton {
                        id: previousMonth
                        width: parent.height
                        height: width
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                        source: "../assets/leftanglearrow.png"
                        onClicked: {
                            control.showPreviousMonth()
                        }
                    }
                    Label {
                        id: dateText
                        text: styleData.title
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                        font.pixelSize: TextSingleton.implicitHeight * 1.25
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    }
                    HoverButton {
                        id: nextMonth
                        width: parent.height
                        height: width
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        anchors.right: parent.right
                        source: "../assets/rightanglearrow.png"
                        onClicked: {
                            control.showNextMonth()
                        }
                    }
                }

                dayOfWeekDelegate: Item {
                    height: dp(30)
                    width: parent.width
                    Rectangle {
                        height: parent.height
                        width: parent.width
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        Label {
                            id: dayOfWeekDelegateText
                            text: Qt.locale().dayName(styleData.dayOfWeek, Locale.ShortFormat)
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                        }
                    }
                }
                dayDelegate: Item {
                    id: container

                    readonly property color sameMonthDateTextColor: "#444"
                    readonly property color selectedDateColor: "#81b1c2"
                    readonly property color selectedDateTextColor: "#4e4e4e"
                    readonly property color differentMonthDateTextColor: "#bbb"
                    readonly property color invalidDatecolor: "#dddddd"

                    Row {
                        id: otherUserRow
                        z: 4
                        anchors {
                            top: parent.top; left: parent.left
                        }

                        Repeater {
                            id: repeater
                            model: {
                                var found = calendarListModel.filter(
                                            function (element) {
                                                return element.date === styleData.date.getTime();
                                }
                                );

                                if(found === undefined)
                                    return 0;

                                return repeater.model = found.length;

                            }
                            Rectangle {
                                id: otherUserMarker
                                width: dp(10)
                                radius: dp(12)
                                height: width
                                color: {
//This works perfectly as the marker is always there simply transparent
                                    var modelObject = calendarListModel.find(
                                                function(obj) {
                                                    return obj.date === styleData.date.getTime();
                                                }
                                                );

                                    if (modelObject === undefined)
                                        return "#00000000";

                                    return modelObject.name !== userName + " " + userSurname ? "#e6b89c" : "#e6b89c";
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    Label {
                        id: dayDelegateText
                        z: 5
                        text: styleData.date.getDate()
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        color:  {
                            var color = invalidDatecolor;
                            if (styleData.valid) {
                                color = styleData.visibleMonth ? sameMonthDateTextColor : differentMonthDateTextColor ;
                                if (styleData.selected) {
                                    color = selectedDateTextColor;
                                }
                            }
                            color ;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

A sample of my JSON used as `calendarListModel` is (extreamly long, but so you can have a full example of changing dates):

```
[{"date":1555671600000,"name":"Joanne Brown","details":"2 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1558090800000,"name":"Joanne Brown","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1559300400000,"name":"Joanne Brown","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1561114800000,"name":"Joanne Brown","details":"2 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1561719600000,"name":"Joanne Brown","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1563534000000,"name":"Joanne Brown","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1565953200000,"name":"Joanne Brown","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1566558000000,"name":"Joanne Brown","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1554894000000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1555066800000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1555153200000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1559127600000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1557486000000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"3 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1561806000000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1563534000000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"5 Hour(s) 30m.","status":1},{"date":1565175600000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1565348400000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1565434800000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1571482800000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577275200000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577880000000,"name":"Kirsten France","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1555930800000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1557140400000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"2 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1558954800000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"2 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1562583600000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1562670000000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1562756400000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1562842800000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1566817200000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"2 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1571050800000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1571137200000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1571223600000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1571310000000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577275200000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577361600000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577880000000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1555844400000,"name":"Jenny Ricketts","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1555930800000,"name":"Jenny Ricketts","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1558954800000,"name":"Jenny Ricketts","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1557140400000,"name":"Jenny Ricketts","details":"1 Hour(s) 40m.","status":1},{"date":1563188400000,"name":"Jenny Ricketts","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1566212400000,"name":"Jenny Ricketts","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1566730800000,"name":"Jenny Ricketts","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1566817200000,"name":"Jenny Ricketts","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1567422000000,"name":"Jenny Ricketts","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1555930800000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1556017200000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1556190000000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1556103600000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1557140400000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"2 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1558954800000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"2 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1559818800000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"5 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1560164400000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1563361200000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"4 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1566817200000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1568545200000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1568631600000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1568718000000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1568804400000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1568890800000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1555671600000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"2 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1554375600000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1554462000000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1558090800000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1558177200000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1558609200000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1560078000000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1560423600000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1560510000000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1560596400000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1566126000000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1567162800000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"1 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1568372400000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1568458800000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1571396400000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1571482800000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1571828400000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1571914800000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1572001200000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1574251200000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1574337600000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1574424000000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577275200000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577361600000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577880000000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1555671600000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"7 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1558004400000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"7 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1558090800000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1558436400000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1569322800000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1569409200000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1569495600000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1569582000000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"7 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1569668400000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1569927600000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1570186800000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1570100400000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1570014000000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1570532400000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1570618800000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577275200000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577361600000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577448000000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577534400000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577793600000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577880000000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577966400000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1578052800000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1554202800000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1554289200000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1554375600000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1554462000000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1554548400000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1554894000000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1555671600000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"2 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1559732400000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1559818800000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1559905200000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1559991600000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1560078000000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"7 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1560250800000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1560337200000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1560423600000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1560510000000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1560596400000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1566298800000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1566385200000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1566471600000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1566558000000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1566990000000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1570705200000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1570791600000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1570878000000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"8 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1573905600000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"7 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1577361600000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"10 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1571482800000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"8 Hour(s) 40m.","status":1},{"date":1571655600000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1571742000000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1571828400000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1571914800000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1572087600000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1574942400000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577275200000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577361600000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577880000000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1572782400000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"7 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1577880000000,"name":"Filippos Katsanis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1556276400000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"7 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1556362800000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1556449200000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1556535600000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1556794800000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1557140400000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"1 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1562410800000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1564225200000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1564398000000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1564657200000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1564743600000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1564830000000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1565002800000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1565262000000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1568026800000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1568286000000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1570705200000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1570791600000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1570878000000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1570964400000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1584964800000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1585051200000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1585137600000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1585224000000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1579521600000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1579608000000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1579694400000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1579780800000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1555671600000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"3 Hour(s) 20m.","status":1},{"date":1561201200000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1562151600000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1562238000000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1562324400000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1565780400000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1565866800000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1565953200000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1566039600000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577275200000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577361600000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577880000000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1579089600000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1579176000000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1579262400000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1579348800000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1588762800000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1588849200000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1588935600000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1589022000000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582113600000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582200000000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582372800000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582286400000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1584619200000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1584705600000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1584792000000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1570273200000,"name":"Tomoko Hirano","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577275200000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577361600000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":0},{"date":1573387200000,"name":"Joanne Brown","details":"4 Hour(s) 30m.","status":1},{"date":1577966400000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1578225600000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1578571200000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1578484800000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1578398400000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1578312000000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1578744000000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1578657600000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1578139200000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1578052800000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1608811200000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":"pending"},{"date":1608724800000,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"Full Day","status":"pending"},{"date":1581422400000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1579089600000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"Half Day (AM)","status":0},{"date":1579089600000,"name":"Charlie Davis","details":"5 Hour(s) 30m.","status":1},{"date":1582459200000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582545600000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582632000000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1585479600000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582804800000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1585652400000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1585738800000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1585911600000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1585998000000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1585825200000,"name":"Katie Prescott","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577448000000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577534400000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577620800000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577707200000,"name":"Sara Turola","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577534400000,"name":"Filippos Katsanis","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1577528422774,"name":"Lisa Duong","details":"0 Hour(s) 40m.","status":1},{"date":1585566000000,"name":"Biliana Zutomarkovic","details":"Half Day (AM)","status":1},{"date":1577966400000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"2 Hour(s) 0m.","status":1},{"date":1582200000000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582113600000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582027200000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"3 Hour(s) 50m.","status":1},{"date":1586775600000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1586862000000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1586948400000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1587034800000,"name":"Alessandro Barca","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582372800000,"name":"Mario Cammarata","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582545600000,"name":"Mario Cammarata","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1582632000000,"name":"Mario Cammarata","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1584619200000,"name":"Mario Cammarata","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1584446400000,"name":"Mario Cammarata","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1584360000000,"name":"Mario Cammarata","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1584273600000,"name":"Mario Cammarata","details":"Full Day","status":1},{"date":1597316400000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"Full Day","status":"pending"},{"date":1597402800000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"Full Day","status":"pending"},{"date":1597489200000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"Full Day","status":"pending"},{"date":1597575600000,"name":"Tania Faenza","details":"Full Day","status":"pending"}]
```

Comment: You could explain to me better what you want since you only point out that something is failing but it is not understood what you are trying to implement.

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc apologies I have only just made edits, during my time cleaning up the question, I further found the issue - and have self answered, always happy with any improvements though! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this working by changing my `Repeater {model: {…}}` code too;

```
model: {
    var found = calendarListModel.filter(
    function (element) {
        return element.date === styleData.date.getTime();
         }
         );
         if(found === undefined)
             return 0;
                 return found.length;
// this was changed from directly assigning the repeater.model as
// return repeater.model = found.length
    }
```